# Storing Key Value Like Data in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, spring-cloud-dataflow

Since Google Cloud Storage supports Object Change Notifications, it fits in a good programming model of enriching objects inserted to a bucket where a service can detect the item and react accordingly. This takes away the need to manually build a notification service around object changes.

However, let's say we store row level data (each data item, e.g. User Profile Name Change/Add) on Cloud Storage with the User Id as the ID, and the actual "name" as the value, it would result in a very large number of small objects in the bucket. While this can then allow a system which analyses this data (say spam detection), is this not recommended? (due to a large number of small objects)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A large number of small objects is fully supported in GCS.

You might, however, be interested in a more structured database approach to storing your user info:

- [Google Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/)
- [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/)
- [Google Cloud Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/)
- [Google Cloud Spanner](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/)

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming!